# How are you connecting two Istio clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, vpn, istio

The scenario:

I have two K8s clusters. One is on-prem, the other is hosted in AWS. I could use Istio to make communication painless and do things like balloon capacity in AWS, but I'm getting hung up on trying to connect them. Reading the documentation, it looks like I need a VPN deployed inside of K8s if I want to have encrypted tunnels so that each internal network can talk to the other side. They're both non-overlapping 10-dots so I have that part done.

Is that correct or am I missing something on how to connect the two K8s clusters?

Answer (score 2):

Having Istio in your cluster is independent of setting up basic communication in between your two clusters. There are a few options that I can think of here:

1. VPN between some nodes in both clusters like you mentioned.
2. BGP peering with [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.2/usage/configuration/bgp) and your existing infrastructure.
3. A router in between your two clusters that understand the internal cluster IPs (This could be with BGP or static routes)
4. [Kubernetes Federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/). V1 is in alpha and V2 is in the implementation phase as of this writing. Not prod ready yet IMO.

Comment: Well, federation is definitely beta, so I'm not enthusiastic about that. Are you using the VPN solution? Which VPN container are you using? How what happens when I have a third cluster I want to add to the mesh?

Comment: Not using cross-cluster communication. VPN is a point to point solution so if you add a 3rd cluster it becomes trickier you have to setup VPNs across all the 3 clusters with different address spaces. VPN won't scale that well but for 2 clusters it would be an ok solution.

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured out I'm basically doing it wrong. Since istio uses TLS - I don't need the VPN for crypto, just connectivity, which is overkill since it's encrypting encrypted traffic. I just need some sort of connectivity between the clusters which we can facilitate on the existing link and I can use EIPs if I don't have that.